# How to display 365 day Calendar in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have to show all 365 days on an events diary (it has to be 365 days, I have no choice).

The app was originally in winforms, it had 12 DataGridView's, one for each month, with one small text line for each day upto 31 lines. We (just) Managed to get it all on screen ( it was done on two rows i.e. Jan-June top 6 DGV's, July-Dec Bottom 6 DGV's).

I need to get the project over to WPF.

My question is regarding speed, the winforms ver wasn't too fast, im wondering whats the best approach for the layout & DB for this app, i.e  more info -

- It uses T-SQL as the diary DB
- Not All days have anything to display (ie no direct binding for text day-> db day enrty)
- DB entries have a date an event description (description is what I need to display)
- A typical Diary has approx 150 entries to display

Any Help Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Can't really help you much on the layout side, however I was required to implement something very similar in silverlight and this is the solution I used which worked pretty well.

1: Implement isolated storage on the application side, this is used as the diary cache

2: On the database side you should store the data as an XML data type

3: When the user logs in immeadiatly display the contents of the diary cache so there's no waiting

4: Next immeadiatly kick off a background worker which communicates back to the database and gets the latest up to date diary information

5: Once the background worker completes, check if any day's data from the db is different from that stored in local cache, if so update the GUI and local cache

6: Run the background worker every 5 minutes following steps 4 & 5 as required

Comment: Some good points, especially 4 & 5, really appreciate the input. As far as speed is concerned apparently its best to use an ObservableCollection<T> which I have done, I also used your suggestion to use a backgroundWorker to update it every so often. As for the layout, I have no idea, so ive simply stuck with a standard data template in an ListView (one for each month as I believe this is better - ie Bind to many ojects with fewer properties as explained at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613546.aspx)